# I have a problem, whenever I open a Crystal Report, I get this error: "Failed to load database information.Error in file temp"

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I've developed a Windows Forms app in vb.net with a report. It works fine on my PC, but when I sent this to my friend and he ran this program , I get an error in report:

> Failed to load database information. Error in file temp.

We both have 64 bit runtime version. I don't know what to do. Please do help!

Comment: What is the database? Where is the database? Show the code where the database is attached to the Crystal report.

Comment: database is on server.

Comment: And One thing is that i've other reports too in my application, they work fine, only this report gives an error. So I don't know what's the problem with this report.

Comment: Does your friend have access to and permissions for the server?

Comment: Yes. i gave him connection string file with exe.